# How to extract Substring from a String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have a String like below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://dns.net/adj/myhost.com/index;size=5x10;zipc=12345;myzon=north_west;|en;tile=10;ord=7jkllk456?"></script>
```

I want to access whatever is between `src="` and `">`. I have developed a code something like below:

```
        int i=str.indexOf("src=\"");
        str=str.substring(i+5);
        i=str.indexOf("\">");
        str=str.substring(0,i);
        System.out.println(str);
```

Do you know if this is the right way? My only worry is that sometimes there could be a space between `src` and `=` or space between `"` and `>` and in this case my code will not work so I was thinking to use Regex. But I am not able to come up with any Regular expression. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Just as a side note: what if there was another attribute after the `src` attribute?  In that case you couldn't parse to `">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to bother with regex, you can do this:

```
testString.split("src\\=")[1].split(">")[0]);
```

Of course it still doesn't solve your other concerns with different formats, but you can still use an applicable regex (like RanRag's answer) with the String.split() instead of the 5 lines of code you were using.

Comment: I used testString.split("src\\s*=\"")[1].split("\\s*\">")[0] and this worked.

Answer (score 2):

This will work, but you should look into [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/), they provide a powerful way to spot patterns and extract text accordingly.

Comment: Woopsie, didn't notice that you were already considering it. In this case, the tutorial that I linked is a great resource, as is the cheat sheet here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is overkill for your situation, but you might want to consider using an HTML parser.  This would take care of all the document formatting issues and let you get at the tags and attributes in a standard way.  While Regex may work for simple HTML, once things become more complicated you could run into trouble (false matches or missed matches).

Here is a list of available open source parsers for Java: http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this regex  `src\s+"[=](.*)"\s+>`.

Lets break it down

`src` match for src in string

`\s+` look for one or more than one occurence of whitespace

`[=]` match for equal to

`(.*)` zero or more than one occurence of text until `"\s>`

Answer (score 0):

If there can't be any escaped double quotes in the string you want, try this expression: `src="([^"]*)"`. This will `src="` and  match anything up to the first `"` that follows and capture the text between the double quotes into group 1 (group 0 is always the entire matched string).

Since whitespace around `=` is allowed, you might extend the expression to `src\s*=\s*"([^"]*)"`.

Just a word of warning: HTML isn't a regular language and thus it can't be parsed using regular expressions. For simple cases like this it is ok but don't fall into the trap and think you can parse more complex html structures.